# Apache RewriteRule for Two URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect the following two URLs:

```
https://www.example.com/blog/content/Das.com
https://www.example.com/blog/content/page/2
```

To:

```
https://www.example.com/blog/content
```

Using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (blog/content/Das.com|blog/content/page/2) /blog/content [L,R=301]
```

But it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question does not make any sense: what you specify as "To" is identical to the second URL before. And it has little to do with the rule you actually coded. So maybe you want to take some time to client the "edit" button to revise your question...

Comment: @arkascha Updated, thank you.

Comment: What's the location of your htaccess?

Comment: ...and where have you placed this directive in your `.htaccess` file in relation to existing directives? The point is, the above directive should already redirect as required providing you've put it at the top of the root `.htaccess` file (and mod_rewrite and `.htaccess` overrides are enabled). (You should still _anchor_ the regex and escape literal dots and it can be "tidied" a bit, but these are secondary to your main problem of it "not working".)

Comment: @AmitVerma In the root directory. Does that affect something?

Comment: @GTSJoe The location of the `.htaccess` file determines the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. If the `.htaccess` file was somewhere other than the root directory (eg. in `/blog` or `/blog/content` - are they both directories?) then that would have explained why the rule you posted was "not working". What about where you have placed this particular rule in the `.htaccess` file (as I asked above) - do you have any other directives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to redirect different requested URLs to the same target URL? That means you will loose the information which URL has originally been requested. So you cannot differ between the two requests any more. If you actually only want to *internally rewrite* those URLs, so that they can be processed by the same controller, then just leave away the `R=301` flags below...

I personally would suggest to implement two separate rules. Readability of code is of high importance, it should be possible to immedately understand what code does even for someone who did not write the code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?blog/content/Das\.com$ /blog/content [R=301,END]
RewriteRule ^/?blog/content/page/2$ /blog/content [R=301,END]
```

But if you prefer a single rule you certainly can combine that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?blog/content/(?:Das\.com|page/)$ /blog/content [R=301,END]
```

For this to work the rewriting module needs to be loaded into the http server obviously. You should prefer to implement such rules in the actual http server's host configuration. You can use a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") in case you do not have control over the normal configuration, but that comes with a performance penalty. And obviously also needs to be enabled first. You'd need to place that file in the top folder of your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` in that case.

In general it is a good idea to start out with a `R=302` temporary redirection and only to change that to a `R=301` permanent redirection once you are sure things work as expected. That prevents annoying caching issues.

Comment: What is the END flag for? Is it the same as the L flag?

Comment: It is similar, but not identical. The `END` flag terminates the rewriting process for the current request. The `L` flag terminates the rewriting process for the current iteration of the process. So it starts again with the next iteration, _unless_ the last iteration has not resulted in any changes to the request. Do yo know that there is an excellent documentation of that tool you are using? It comes with good examples and even explains those flags: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html